Error with leaflet on angular 17 standalone app
I'm a recent angular user.
I'm trying to add a leaflet map to my project.
I saw that I had to use a service to avoid errors related to window.
I used the following example: https://github.com/NickToony/universal-starter-leaflet-example
I made my map.service.tst file like this:
import { Injectable, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class MapService {

  public L = null;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      this.L = require('leaflet');
    }
  }

}

and my map.component.ts file like this:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from '../services/map.service';
import { Map } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrl: './map.component.css',
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  public message!: string;
  private map!: Map;

  constructor(private mapService: MapService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.mapService.L) {
      // Leaflet is loaded - load the map!
      this.message = 'Map Loaded';
      this.setupMap();
    } else {
      // When the server renders it, it'll show this.
      this.message = 'Map not loaded';
    }
  }

  private setupMap() {
    if (!this.mapService || !this.mapService.L) {
      console.error('mapService is not initialized');
      return;
    }

    // Create the map in the #map container
    this.map = this.mapService.L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    // Add a tilelayer
    this.mapService.L.tileLayer(
      'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      {
        attribution:
          'copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>,' +
          ' Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://hot.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team</a>'
      }
    ).addTo(this.map);

  }
}

in map.component.ts, I have two errors:

The 'map' property doesn't exist on the 'never' type.
The 'tileLayer' property doesn't exist on the 'never' type.

I can't figure out how to get past these two errors.

Nick Felker already provided a great answer why you get these errors. You may also be able to use @types/leaflet instead of writing your own typings.
However, you don't really need that service. Here is another example using Angular with Leaflet:

Create Angular app with ng new leaflet-angular-example
Install Leaflet with npm install leaflet
Install typings for Leaflet with npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet
Create a component with ng g component map
Change app.component.html

<main>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>  
</main>


Change app.routes.ts

import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'map', component: MapComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/map', pathMatch: 'full' },
];


Change styles.scss

body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100wh;
    margin: 0;
}


Update angular.json by adding node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css to styles

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "leaflet-angular-example": {
      // ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            // ...
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"  // <-- add this line
            ],
            // ...


Change map.component.html

<div id="map" #map>
</div>


Change map.component.scss

#map {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}


Change map.component.ts

import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Map, map, tileLayer } from 'leaflet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrl: './map.component.scss'
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('map')
  mapElementRef: ElementRef = null!;

  private _map: Map = null!;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this._map = map(this.mapElementRef.nativeElement)
        .setView([46.801111, 8.226667], 8);

    tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        // add a link to OpenStreetMap (omitted here for shorter line width)
        attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap'
    }).addTo(this._map);

  }

}


When I see public L = null;, my understanding is that TypeScript infers that type to be null. So when you call mapService.L.tileLayer, you're basically trying to call null.tileLayer, which throws as expected.
I believe you'd need to modify the type of L to be more expanisve:
public L: any = null;

That should then allow you to call any method and use any property.
Since you're setting L to require('leaflet'), the type is not going to be implicitly provided.
You could try defining the type of L more narrowly if you're really keen on type-safety:
public L: {
  map: (mapName: string) => ...
  tileLayer: (layerUrl: string, ...) => ...
  ...
} | null = null;

